# What types of tree are these?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, tree-care

I would like to know the names of these trees. And whether the small black berry looking fruits are edible.

Edit: The small tree is not doing well, so I want to learn more about this tree in order to give it the best chance to survive.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No matter the species, we'll get that for you, but the trunks of those trees are compromised.  Pull that rock, any soil or mulch away from the trunk.  That allows water to stay on the trunk too long and promotes a sort of early decomposition.  Bacteria get going and will soon kill the vascular system of your tree (s).  I only saw the purple leaf plum's trunk and gravel but I am assuming the other has been done the same way: too much gravel up on the trunk.

Comment: If there's landscape fabric or plastic under the rock, pull that away from the trunk as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will try you guys' advice. From your experience, does the first tree look salvageable or do you think it's a goner?

Comment: Looks FINE KubiK!  The IDs are good.  Do you have plastic beneath the gravel?  If so get rid of it.  It will not help at all to deter weeds.  It will harbor insects, disease, and inhibit water...and inhibit soil life.  Your plum needs THINNING.  It is way too dense, as these trees usually are.  Air needs to flow through that tree to keep fungus at bay. The birds will eat the berries just fine.  That tree is showing heat and dehydration with the curling leaves.  Not enough water is getting to its feeder roots that got covered with the rock and (plastic)?

Comment: Yes there is black garden fabric underneath, which I will remove. And thanks, I will follow your other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one looks like Hawthorn, or *Crataegus*. But for more specific ID we need to see the fruits as well. See [here](https://pestleherbs.co.uk/product/hawthorn/) for an example with the same leaf shape.

The second one is a *Prunus*, I think a *Prunus serrulata 'Royal Burgundy'* (as seen [here](https://www.mailordertrees.co.uk/products/prunus-royal-burgundy-flowering-cherry-tree)), but it could be another variety as well. This cherry tree is more ornamental, and not meant for fruit production. So the fruits are edible, but won't taste as good as the real cherry. See [here](https://hortnews.extension.iastate.edu/2003/8-8-2003/edilbility.html) about edibility of fruit that come from ornamental trees.

Your trees look indeed not in perfect shape, and stormy gives you already some advice. Maybe more people (arborists) here can give you more advice.